# How to solve $\int \sin(x) e^{\sin(x)-x} (\sin(x)-x) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I was trying to solve the integration of $\int \sin(x) e^{\sin(x)-x} (\sin(x)-x) dx$ with integration by parts, but with no success.

I also tried to expend the expression to:

$\int \sin^2(x) e^{\sin(x)-x} dx - \int x\sin(x) e^{\sin(x)-x} dx$

Also this didn't really help. Maybe someone has better ideas?

Comment: where did you found this integral?

Comment: It doesn't have any antiderivative. Even [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\int+sin%28x%29+e^{sin%28x%29-x}+%28sin%28x%29-x%29+dx) can't integrate it.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas I have seen many times in the past where a solution exists that wolfram cannot find...

Comment: @ Dr. Sonnhard Graubner， the integral is the outcome of a mathematical model, which intends to describe the average number of neighbors of a single node/host in a given network.

Comment: @jm324354, totally agree. if W|A could solve this directly, then I don't have to post it here ;) Also tools like wxMaxima could not solve it directly. But I think with some steps of simplifications it should be solvable by the machines ...

Comment: @ChunleiA Have you thought about applying numerical techniques?

Comment: I also tried to learn something from one of the previous posts here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636803/how-to-integrate-a-three-products, which seems a bit similar to my problem. So far it doesn't work out.

Comment: @Mattos, thanks for the hint. I don't have knowledge about numerical techniques, but now I am looking for some materials about it.

Comment: The only way in which this integral *might* possess a closed form is if we were to add $0$ and $\infty$ as limits of integration, and then *try* to express it in terms of [Bessel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) and [Struve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function) functions.