# Integral problem: $\int e^{3t}(\cos(t))^{3}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a problem with this integral:
$\int e^{3t}(\cos(t))^{3}dt$

I try to do this by parts or substitution but I did not manage to do count this. I will be glad for any tips to solve this the fastest way.

Comment: or use the fact $\cos(t)=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-it} + \mathrm{e}^{it}}{2}$. Then expand the equation and collect terms and integrate with respect t.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

Use $$\cos3t=4\cos^3t-3\cos t\iff \cos t=\frac{\cos3t+3\cos t}4$$

then [this](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Integral_of_Product_of_Exponential_with_Sine_or_Cosine) or utilize [Integrate $e^{ax}\sin(bx)?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540295/integrate-eax-sinbx)

Answer (score 1):

use the trigonometric identity $$\cos 3x=4\cos^3x-3\cos x$$  the integral becomes $$\int e^{3t}\frac{1}{4}(\cos 3x +3\cos x)dx$$ now apply integration by parts.