# $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1 - e^{-px} \sin(x)}{x} dx$ Evaluate Integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How do I solve the integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1 - e^{-px} \sin(x)}{x} dx$$

I know the answer is   $ \arctan(p) $   but have no idea as to how to show that.

Any hints welcome!

Thanks

Comment: This integral is divergent. Have you a typo?

Answer (score 1):

I **assume** that you are evaluating
\begin{align}
-\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-px} \sin x}{x} dx,\tag1
\end{align}
since 
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-e^{-px} \sin x}{x} dx
\end{align}
does not converge.

Therefore, $(1)$ can be evaluated using the technique of “Feynman Integration”.
\begin{align}
I(p)&=-\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-px} \sin x}{x} dx\\
\frac{dI}{dp}&=-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{d}{dp}\left(\frac{ e^{-px} \sin x}{x}\right)\ dx\\
I'(p)&=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-px} \sin x\ dx\tag2\\
&=\frac{1}{p^2+1},
\end{align}
where $(2)$ can be evaluated using IBP twice. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540295/integrate-eax-sinbx). Hence
\begin{align}
\frac{dI}{dp}&=\frac{1}{p^2+1}\\
I&=\int\frac{1}{p^2+1}\ dp\\
&=\tan^{-1}(p)+C.
\end{align}
Now, we let $p \to\infty$ so that our integrand is $\lim\limits_{p\to\infty}I(p)=0$, implying that $C = -\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. Thus
$$
\begin{align}
-\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-px} \sin x}{x} dx=\tan^{-1}(p)-\dfrac{\pi}{2}.
\end{align}
$$