# Nowhere differentiable Fourier transform

Tags: derivatives, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Is there any $L_1$ function such that its fourier transform is in $L_1$ and the fourier transform is nowhere differentiable? Or every such Fourier transform must be differentiable a.e.?

Comment: If the function is continuous and compact supported, then is going to be bounded, so if it is also $L^1$ it will be also $L^2$, then its Fourier Transform is going to be an Analytic function (so a smooth transform), due to [Paley–Wiener theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20Paley%E2%80%93Wiener,Wiener%20(1894%E2%80%931964).). So your counter-example, or it will be a discontinuous function, or a continuous function in the whole line as domain.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ be a bounded, nowhere differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $g$ be a standard normal pdf. Then $gf$ is nowhere differentiable and in $L^2$. Also $\hat{(gf)} = \hat{g} * \hat{f} $. The fourier transform of a Gaussian is Gaussian, and convolving with a smooth function makes a smooth function, so $\hat{(gf)}$ is smooth and in $L^2$. So this exhibits a smooth function whose Fourier transform is nowhere differentiable. I think this is correct (?). Does it answer your question?

Comment: I guess you should still explain whether/when $\hat g * \hat f$ is $L^1$

Comment: I think $\hat{gf}$ may not be in $L^2$.

Comment: @Chaos My reasoning was that $g \in L^2$ (I think), so because $f$ is bounded, $gf \in L^2$. So the Fourier transform operator sends it to another element in $L^2$. (This latter Fourier transform is defined by extending the usual formula from the dense set of smooth compactly supported functions.) Oh but I see that its not clear the Fourier transform is in $L^1$... and perhaps that is not true?

Comment: @user8268 I think the best I can do is argue that it is in $L^2$.

Comment: @AreaMan Oh I see it's in $L^2$. But we can't say it's in $L^1$. There are some counterexamples .