# Fourier transform of $C^1$ class function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am struggle to prove the following theorem.

If $f$ $\in$ $C^1$ and $f$ , $f'$ $\in$ $L^1$ , then $\mathcal{F}$$f$ $\in$$L^1$.

($\mathcal{F}$$f$ is Fourier transform of $f$ )

I doubt that whether this theorem is right.

Please tell me proof or counterexample.

(following statement is supplement)

I already know that $f$ is bounded , $\mathcal{F}$$f$ $\in$ $L^2$ and $f$ $\in$ $L^2$ under the hypothesis.

And, since $f$, $f'$ $\in$ $L^1$ then $\mathcal{F}$$f$ , $\mathcal{F}$$f'$ is bounded.

Comment: $f' \in L^2$ so $\mathcal{F} [f'] = i\omega \hat{f} \in L^2$ whence $\langle 1/(1+|\omega|),(1+|\omega|) |\hat{f}| \rangle \le ...$

Comment: @reuns Why f' is belong to L2 ?

Comment: @reuns If $f'$ is bounded, your inequality is correct. But, only $f'$ in $L^1$, can't  lead $f'$ is bounded.

Comment: Sorry I missed the ambiguity : you should read  $C^1$ as the Banach space with sup norm of $f$ and $f'$. If you read it as just "continuously differentiable" it is very possible the claim isn't true

Comment: Otherwise we can look at something like $f' \ast |x|^{-1/2+\epsilon}$ to obtain that $(1+| \omega|^{1/2+\epsilon}) \hat{f} \in L^2$