# Is there a compactly supported differentiable function that is NOT the Fourier transform of an L1 function?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

In my [answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4880068/405572), I discussed the example of compactly supported continuous function
$$g(x)=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\frac12 -x}{\log(x)},&0<x\leq1/2\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
which is not the Fourier transform of any $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$, i.e. $g\not\in \mathcal F(L^1(\mathbb R))$. Looking through the proof, I think that one can smooth out $g$ at $x=\frac 12$, and get a function $\tilde g \in C_c(\mathbb R)$, supported on $[0,\frac 12]$, infinitely differentiable at EVERY point besides $x=0$ (though not even once differentiable at $x=0$), which is not in $ \mathcal F(L^1(\mathbb R))$.

I am now wondering if there is an example of compactly supported function $G\in C_c(\mathbb R)$ which is differentiable at every point, which is is still not in $ \mathcal F(L^1(\mathbb R))$