# Integration of this integral using parts

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

What is the integral of $$\int e^{ax}.sin(bx)dx$$ I used LIATE rule but even after that I am going round and round but not getting the answer.

Comment: **Hint:** this is $$\Im\left(\int e^{(a+ib)x}dx\right).$$

Comment: Please state LIATE rule in the question.

Comment: Can you give one more hint

Comment: Logarithmic ,inverse,algebraic,trigo,exponential i thought its well known.

Comment: Duplicate: [$\displaystyle\int e^{ax}\sin(bx)\,\mathrm{d}x$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/540295/201168). See also this [thread](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic411.html) in the Integrals and Series forum detailing three different ways to evaluate that integral.

Answer (score 1):

$$
du = \mathrm{e}^{ax}, u = \frac{1}{a}\mathrm{e}^{ax}\\
v = \sin (bx), dv = b\cos (bx)
$$
then we get
$$
I = \int \mathrm{e}^{ax}\sin (bx) dx = \frac{1}{a}\mathrm{e}^{ax}\sin (bx) - \frac{b}{a}\int \mathrm{e}^{ax}\cos (bx)dx
$$
then we have 
$$
\int \mathrm{e}^{ax}\cos (bx)dx
$$
using by parts again
$$
du = \mathrm{e}^{ax}, u = \frac{1}{a}\mathrm{e}^{ax}\\
v = \cos (bx), dv = -b\sin (bx)
$$
we have
$$
\int \mathrm{e}^{ax}\cos (bx)dx = \frac{1}{a}\mathrm{e}^{ax}\cos (bx) + \frac{b}{a}\int \mathrm{e}^{ax}\sin (bx)dx = \frac{1}{a}\mathrm{e}^{ax}\cos (bx) + \frac{b}{a}I
$$
so putting it all together we find
$$
I = \frac{1}{a}\mathrm{e}^{ax}\sin (bx)-\frac{b}{a}\left[\frac{1}{a}\mathrm{e}^{ax}\cos (bx) + \frac{b}{a}I\right] = \frac{1}{a}\mathrm{e}^{ax}\sin (bx)-\frac{b}{a^2}\mathrm{e}^{ax}\cos (bx) -\frac{b}{a^2}I
$$
solve for $I$ i.e. your integral.